# Not able to pass Query to java spark program in Yarn cluster mode

Tags: java, apache-spark, talend

Talend 7.1, MapR6.0 Distribution, Spark 2.2,

I have a Talend job (master) which calls Child spark job to execute hive-query after setting Spark-hive context. This Query to be executed is passed from Master to Child spark job.

Query can have complicated hive joins & at times even special characters backtick, !, tilda, @, can be used by user.

If child spark job is run in Spark Yarn client mode, any query runs fine. But if same is executed in Cluster mode & if query has \n or \t or backtick(`) - it gets failed, even in launching spark session. Mostly query itself is geeting corrupted during passing from Master to child.

I am thinking of converting Query string to Hex or Unicode to avoid getting corrupted due to special character and later convert back in spark job. Please suggest if any better solution.

Comment: any update on how you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of points regarding mapR distribution use for Talend Yarn Cluster mode job:

1. Cluster mode spark job would not be able to fetch any jar from ../lib directory (not even talend specific routines.jar). You need to pass it explicitly to drivers along with other spark jars.
2. Any hive query or context parameters which has space, \n, ect.. gets broken and not full string is passed from Master to worker nodes running spark job in cluster mode [ this works fine in client mode ].
3. You cannot update any context variable accross jobs in Talend BD spark job (like use one tJava to update context variables & expect it to use it in another components - Doesn't work!!)

Considering above, few work arounds:

Appraoch-1: You can replace(read remove) all space, \n etc with some character (like @@@) and replace back later in Spark job. Note: this will fail for few special characters like ` .

Approach-2: All queries, parameters which can have space or special character or need explicit parsing - put it in a file, pass this file to hdfs & read the file in Spark job to get all parameters as needed.
Please note, when you read files in Spark job - flow can be treated as RDD (& schema as well) which can be parsed to get all variables.